# HTML Form with PHP: $_POST is not setting on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

**Background:**
I have looked through the variations on this question and solutions, but I have not found one that applies to my situation. I know I'm most likely overlooking something incredibly obvious, but it's been hours and I can't for the life of me pinpoint what it is. I'm following along with this tutorial but making it my own: https://www.taniarascia.com/create-a-simple-database-app-connecting-to-mysql-with-php/.

**What happens:** When I click the submit button, nothing happens. I see "not set" displayed on the screen when the page loads and after clicking submit, so I know I'm in my else block, which means $_POST is not being set.

**What I expect to happen:** I expect to see "not set" on page load, but then once I have filled out the form and clicked submit, I expect to see "set" in my echo statement to indicate that I'm in my if statement and isset($_POST['submit']) is true/successful, followed by "Success" indicating that the try code block was successful, plus the values I entered in the form fields appearing in the database. For now, though, I'd just be happy if I got that first "set" to display.

**I have tried:** I've tried breaking out the php into a separate file and linking it up to the form via action="thatfile.php", but I get the same result. I've also tried using "get" instead of "post" for the method and $_REQUEST instead of $_POST, but again, same outcome - "not set" displayed, no data in the db.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require "../config.php";
    echo "set";

    try  {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        
        $new_item = array(
            "luggage" => $_POST['luggage'],
            "category" => $_POST['category'],
            "item" => $_POST['item'],
            "description" => $_POST['description']
        );

        $sql = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
                "stuff",
                implode(", ", array_keys($new_item)),
                ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_item))
        );
        
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($new_item);
        echo "Success";
    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "not set";
}

?>

<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<h1>Add An Item</h1>

<form method="post">
    <label for="item">Luggage</label>
    <input type="text" name="luggage" id="luggage"></form>

    <label for="item">Category</label>
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category"></form>

    <label for="item">Item</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item"></form>

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

    <a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Are you rendering the required other HTML tags like html, head, body etc...?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Good catch - somewhere along the line I lost my <?php include "header.php"; ?>. I added it back in, but am still having the same issue.

Comment: _General Point_ `not set` is not really much help. In future try to make you error message useful like `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: @RiggsFolly Really good note - have made this change and get an empty array. Both really good notes. This code will definitely need some work as I go.

Comment: @RiggsFolly http:// localhost/myapp/public/create.php (no space between the // and the localhost, it just automatically removed my http:// otherwise)

Comment: Check the answer from @AbraCadaver they spotted the woopsie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the form `</form>` multiple times before the final end of the form `</form>` so the submit is not in the form.  Remove these:

```
 <label for="item">Luggage</label>
    <input type="text" name="luggage" id="luggage"></form> ***HERE***

    <label for="item">Category</label>
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category"></form> ***HERE***

    <label for="item">Item</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item"></form> ***HERE***
```

Comment: I upvoted, although I kind of feel this should just be closed as a typo.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know.  I looked at it over and over and never saw an issue, so was excited when I finally saw it. ;-)

Comment: Yep, as suspected, I AM A FOOL! Thank you SO much!